# Generated token is not able to access Graph APi to read shared mailbox messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Facing token permission issue while trying to access Graph API from postman.

We have app id created for our shared mailbox and this app id has been granted below permissions for Graph API-
•    Microsoft Graph \ Read user mail  \ Delegated
•    Microsoft Graph \ Read and write access to user mail \ Delegated
•    Microsoft Graph \ Send mail as a user \ Delegated
•    Microsoft Graph \ Read user mailbox settings \ Delegated
•    Microsoft Graph \ Read and write user mailbox settings \ Delegated

We ae able to generate the token from URL(https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/token)
[emphasized text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvNd8.png)
 While using this token to access graph API using below URL for reading the shared mailbox messages we are error- 
  • https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/Inbox/messages 
  • https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

Error Message:- 
"The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the messages of a shared mailbox, you need the **Mail.Read.Shared** permission.

And then access the message with the following url:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{shared_mailbox_id}/messages
```

---

**Update:**

**A. If you want to specify scopes, you need to use [Azure AD V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview). Azure AD V1 only supports resource, but V2 supports scopes.**

V2 authorization endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

V2 token endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**B. Register an application in Azure AD, add necessary permission, and click grant admin consent for your organization**

[image]

**C. Acquire a token with [oauth2 auth code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). Here I will use postman for convenience.** 
[image]

Click request token, you will be asked to enter your credentials. (if not, please clear cookies in postman)
[image]

**D. Then I can get an access token with required permission.**

[image]

E. Finally, I can use the token to get the messages from shared mailbox

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jack. Would you also suggest **Mail.ReadWrite.Shared** permission be able to  respond on behalf of this mailbox via our app?

Comment: @kratiAgarwal Mail.ReadWrite.Shared permission allows the app to create, read, update, and delete mail that the user has permission to access, including the user's own and shared mail. Does not include permission to send mail.

Comment: What access would I need to be able to respond to an email coming in the shared mailbox?

Comment: Mail.Send.Shared.  For more details, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mail-from-other-user

Comment: Shared Mailbox has got  Mail.Read.Shared permission but still we are getting same error.                                                                                                         "The token contains no permissions or permissions can not be understood."

Comment: Check the token in https://jwt.io/ , to see if the token contains the required permission.

Comment: there is no permission mentioned in generated Token while i am trying to decode it

Comment: What is the post data ?  Could you please add it to your question ?

Comment: I am generating token as :-
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/token  
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body :
grant_type :client_credentials
client_id: Our Application Client-ID
client_secret: Our Application Client-Secret
Resource: https://graph.microsoft.com
Scope: Mail.Read.Shared

Comment: You were getting a token with application permission. However, this API needs delegated permission.  You need to get a token as a user.

Comment: Could you please help us to understand how we can generate token as a user. We have followed steps mentioned in this url : "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user" -> Get access on behalf of a user. But we are getting error as: http 404 error.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jack for helping us. We are able to generate the token and read /send messages of shared mailbox.