# Graph PATCH Categories in shared mailbox

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to set mail categories from an Outlook AddIn, via MS Graph.
When I call the PATCH for a users mailbox, this is working like a charme. Like this:

`PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{some-users-mail-address}/messages/{message-id-to-categorize}`

If I use a share mailbox instead I get an error 403.
I already added the permission:

```
Mail.ReadWrite 
Application 
Read and write mail in all mailboxes
```

This should be enough, right? From the description, I'd expect this to include the shared mailboxes, too.

I found there is a delegated permission `Mail.ReadWrite.Shared`, but I cannot use it since I am not in a context with a user and is not selectable as application permission.

Found this:
[Generated token is not able to access Graph APi to read shared mailbox messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474930/generated-token-is-not-able-to-access-graph-api-to-read-shared-mailbox-messages)
Admin consent is given for all scopes.

EDIT: If I check the token as Shiva Keshav Varma suggested it prints:

```
"aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
"idtyp": "app",
"roles": [
  "Mail.ReadWrite",
  "User.ReadWrite.All",
  "Directory.Read.All",
  "User.Read.All",
  "Mail.Read",
  "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite"
],
"ver": "1.0",
```

Comment: Check the token in https://jwt.ms and see if those permissions are present in token

Comment: It is an expected behavior. Please refer to the following documentation- learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-share-messages-folders